# AttributeError 'tuple' object has no attribute 'pie' - matplotlib

Tags: python, tkinter, matplotlib

estoy intentando hacer un grafico de torta con matplotlib para agregarlo a una interfaz grafica de tkinter, pero me salta ese error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo que es

```
    Labels = 'Pendientes positivas', 'Pendientes negativas', 'Resistencias horizontales'
    sizes = [pendientes_positivas, pendientes_negativas, horizontales]
    graficoTorta = plt.subplots()
    graficoTorta.pie(sizes, labels = Labels)
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(graficoTorta, frame_Resistencias_M5)
    canvas.get_tk_widget().place(x = 400, y = 60)
```

Las variables que van dentro de sizes son enteros que adquieren sus valores en otra parte del programa.

Ademas cuando abro la lista de la clase no me aparece 'pie' como un atributo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nose si tenga algo que ver pero imagino que debería estar ahí.
Me base en un codigo de un ejemplo de la documentacion de matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Pie chart, where the slices will be ordered and plotted counter-clockwise:
labels = 'Frogs', 'Hogs', 'Dogs', 'Logs'
sizes = [15, 30, 45, 10]
explode = (0, 0.1, 0, 0)  # only "explode" the 2nd slice (i.e. 'Hogs')

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.pie(sizes, explode=explode, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%',
        shadow=True, startangle=90)
ax1.axis('equal')  # Equal aspect ratio ensures that pie is drawn as a circle.
plt.show()
```

Que me genera la siguiente grafica

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error dice:

> Tuple has no atribute pie

lanzado por la línea:

```
graficoTorta.pie(sizes, labels = Labels)
```

la razón es que `graficoTorta` es como indica el error una tupla, ya que viene definido por :

```
graficoTorta = plt.subplots()
```

[`matplotlib.pyplot.subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) retorna efectivamente una tupla de dos elementos:

- El primer item es una instancia de `matplotlib.figure.Figure` que es el contenedor general usado en matplotlib como área de dibujado.
- El segundo item una instancia de `matplotlib.Axes` o un array NumPy de ellos si se crea una matriz de subplots indicándolo con los argumentos `nrows` y `ncols`. `Axes` es un subcontenedor posicionado dentro de una figura y donde se muestra la grafica, conteniendo los ejes, marcas, rejilla, lineas y polígonos para dibujar la gráfica, etc.

Las [estructura general](https://matplotlib.org/1.5.1/faq/usage_faq.html#parts-of-a-figure) es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El método `pie` es un método de `matplotlib.Axes`, no puedes usarlo directamente sobre la salida de `matplotlib.subplots`, sino que debes obtener la instancia del eje en el que quieres crear el grafico indizando o desempaquetando el segundo item de la lista que retorna como se explica arriba:

```
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1400x600")
frame_Resistencias_M5 = tk.Frame(root)
frame_Resistencias_M5.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

pendientes_negativas = 12
pendientes_positivas = 15
horizontales = 6

labels = 'Pendientes positivas', 'Pendientes negativas', 'Resistencias horizontales'
sizes = [pendientes_positivas, pendientes_negativas, horizontales]
figura, eje = plt.subplots()    # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
eje.pie(sizes, labels=labels)   # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figura, frame_Resistencias_M5)
canvas.get_tk_widget().place(x=400, y=60)

root.mainloop()
```